# Magento logins to another customer account (mixed accounts)

Tags: customer, login, bug, magento-1.9.2

Some customers are reporting a bug that when they login to their account are redirected to another random customer account where they can see all the other customer data (orders, addresses, everything).

Comment: what are you using for sessions? You can check this in etc/local.xml

Comment: Are you using any third party extensions ?

Comment: Are you using some external cache engine such as Varnish?

Comment: For sessions I'm using files, I'm using one external extension for shipping costs calculator, and for cache I have it activated in External Full Page Cache Settings > Zend Full Page Cache

Comment: Unfortunately this is a problem were I can't see any way to help you with. If you have only one module installed and didn't touch the core it can be everything. E.g. a opcache/apc problem with another shop on the same machine.

Comment: Same problem here, how did you solve this?